# FastAPI + Postgres + SQLAlchemy - Fatal: remaining connection slots are reserved

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, jinja2, fastapi

I am using FastAPI as a full stack with Jinja2 template.
The main problem is SQLalchemy and postgres

Here's example of main page

```
async def read_posts(request: Request, page: int = 1, page_size: int = 12, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
   posts = db.query(models.Post).offset(start).limit(end).all()
   return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request, "posts": posts})
```

I just have a blog with a lot of posts, and speed of loading page is very slow, I think I somehow wrongly build queries to the database, but can't find what I did wrong, it is very simple app.

But the main problem is that website is not able to withstand a load, there's statistics from one of the services to check the load
[LOAD STATS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciq11.jpg)

here's the logs of error when there is load

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections
```

i find out that is connection leak, but i can't find the source of the problem. I spent 2 days to find the problem and got nothing

Comment: That error message is only telling you that there are too many active connections compared to what the server will allow - it isn't really the cause of your problem, which sounds like stems from having too many slow queries; start by finding out which queries are slow and then work backwards from there. You can also increase the connection limit - idle connections are cheap, but if they're kept busy running queries that doesn't scale, increasing the number of connections won't help in any way.

Comment: You need to show us how you are managing your connections.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer

in FastApi you connect to database like this

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker


SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = "sqlite:///./my.db"
engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL, connect_args={"check_same_thread": False})

# Dependency
def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db    
    finally:
        db.close()
```

Most important part is get_db(), so you call this command wherever you access the database and think when your query is ended it will finally close, but it won't happen.
When you return posts to template, as in the example above, there is still connection to database and because of it there's connection overflow.

It won't happen if you use JsonResponse for example, but with TemplateResponse database will still connected and working